# Slow file transfer issue with usb storage

Tags: usb, usb-drive

Im using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS , the problem happens when i try to copy files from my HDD to Pendrive . Transmission slows down in the very last time and stuck for few minutes which is very annoying ! Can anyone help please ! its a pain ! note that my hdd's drives are formatted with ntfs partition .

Comment: Please don't swear in posts. If you want to add a picture add a link to it to your question and I'll integrate it in the post itself. Not sure what's the problem, Transmission slows down (download / upload speed) when you copy files from your HDD to a pen drive?

Comment: Nope bro , it happens when i try to send some files to pendrive the copy-paste speed slows down and stuck at 0 minutes left stage .sorry im totally new here

Comment: Try this: in Terminal, install `pv` (`sudo apt-get install pv`), create a 100MB test file (`dd if=/dev/zero of=file -iflag=fullblock bs=1M count=100 && sync`) and copy it to your pendrive using `pv` (`pv file /media/username/pendrive`) (replace `/media/username/pendrive` with the actual path to the pendrive). You may then remove the test file and uninstall `pv` (`rm file && sudo apt-get remove pv`). Which speed do you get?

Comment: Also to notify users of your comments use @username (remove spaces in the username if present, e.g. @AllenQuatermain)

Comment: Does a "sync" command at a terminal force the finish?  Might be a delayed write for performance and to save the flash filesystem from repeated writes to the same (directory) blocks.

Comment: Thanks for your response . problem solved by dropping cache . :D @kos

Answer (score 4):

Linux kernel implements the strategy that all read-writes from/to external devices go though the RAM (buffer).

So sometimes it can be ***seen*** graphically that at first the contents are going very fast from disk to the external USB but its slowing down at the last moment, this happens when the contents are being transferred from buffer to the USB device. This solely depends on how speedy your USB are and also depends on disk speed at first while transferring from disk to buffer. Sometimes it can also happen that you don't have sufficient free buffer to carry out the operation smoothly.

I would suggest you to look at `iotop` to get a better idea on this. You can install `iotop` by :

```
sudo apt-get install iotop
```